# How do I tag users to a post

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website where a user can upload post and also tag other users, just like facebook. I have successfully implemented a postform and also added a tag field to manytomany field in model. I do not have an idea on this particular topic. So how do i tag a user to a post, when postform is submitted then the users tagged will be selected automatically when the post is saved in admin, so that when i check on the post in admin i will be able to see tagged users selected in manytomany field. I have a form field where the username who you want to tag will be entered before the form is submitted in autocomplete.

Model.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    image_caption = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_someone = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='tagged_users', blank=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'image_caption', 
            'tag_someone',
        )
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def upload_view(request):
    ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(File, fields=('files',), extra=20)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.poster_profile = request.user
            post.save()   
            form.save_m2m()

            for f in formset:
                try:
                    photo = File(post=post, files=f.cleaned_data['files'])
                    photo.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    break
            return redirect('/')              
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormset(queryset=File.objects.none())
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

Upload.html

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="file">
 <div class="ui-widget"> 
    <input type="text" name="tag_someone" class="form-control autocomplete" maxlength="50"id="id_tag_someone" placeholder="Enter username">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Post</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a commit=false in your save call. According [to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) a commit=false in the save() call will not apply the ManyToMany relationships. They need to be applied "manually":

```py
[...]
post = form.save(commit=False)
post.poster_profile = request.user
post.save()
form.save_m2m() # this line will save the ManyToMany relationships of the form
[...]
```

Comment: @Tartempion...i added form.save_m2m(), my post is not submitting.

Comment: @MrHize can you update your code on the first message to see the differences?

Comment: I just added form.save_m2m() and the bottom of post.save() in views. When I click on post button, the post is not saving and it redirect to same page.

Comment: Can you still edit your code on the first message for people who will come here to see what have been done.
If your form is not saved at all but was save before means that there is a problem somewhere in this part of the code. Does Django raise an exception?

Comment: I have added your code to my question form.save_m2m() in views.py. I am not getting any error, just that when I click on post the page just reload and form not saved.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by replacing this (Input field):

```
<input type="text" name="tag_someone" class="form-control autocomplete" maxlength="50"id="id_tag_someone" placeholder="Enter username">
```

to this (Select field):

```
<label for="id_tag_someone">Tag someone:</label><br>
<select name="tag_someone" id="id_tag_someone" multiple="" class="chosen w-100">
{% for user in tag_list_users %}
<option value="{{user.pk}}">{{user}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```